# Statitical comparison of regression prediction to sample of data

Tags: regression, t-test, predictive-models, z-test

I have a dataset, let's call it data1(x,y), where the data y is measured at 16 values of x. I use this dataset to fit to a 3-parameter model. I can obtain estimates for the three model coefficents together with their standard errors, and can compute the usual 95% confidence and prediction intervals across the data space.

I now have a smaller dataset, let's call it data2(x,y), where I have 5 measurements of y at a single value of x. I would like to test the hypotheses that the data obtained in data2 comes from a distribution that has the same mean and variance as the prediction from the model at the particular value of x.

I am struggling somewhat in applying a T-test and a Z-test as, among onther things, I am not sure how I would interpret the degrees of freedom of the prediction relative to those of the measurements form data2. Could anybody offer any advice on how to approach this, and if there is an example I could look at?

Thank you in advance,

Davide